# AngularJS relative url routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angular-routing

I have my backend web framework loading my AngularJS app with following URL

```
http://localhost/New/Alpha/App
```

I also have it set up so that anything after `App` will still load the same thing

```
http://localhost/New/Alpha/App/home
http://localhost/New/Alpha/App/settings
...
```

I'm trying to make my AngularJS app to work in the way that it would pick up the bit of URL after `App` and load a controller/template accordingly. I have a problem with routing in my AngularJS app though

```
var main = angular.module("main", ["ui.bootstrap", "ngRoute"]);

main.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("home", {
        templateUrl: "assets/tpl/home.html",
        controller: "mainController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "fail"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

main.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
    console.log("home")
});
```

If I try this URL

```
http://localhost/New/Alpha/App/home
```

it changes the URL to

```
http://localhost/fail
```

instead of leaving the URL as it is and loading the template/controller. If however I change the config and give it a full relative URL it does work as supposed to

```
.when("/New/Alpha/App/home", {
    templateUrl: "assets/tpl/home.html",
    controller: "mainController"
})
```

My problem is, that the part of URL before `App` - `/New/Alpha` cannot be hardcoded in. It could be `/New/Beta`, `/New/Gamma`, etc.

Is what I want to do possible at all without hardcoding the full relative URL match?

**UPDATE** Sorry, forgot to mention that the number of URL segments before `App` can change, as in it could be `/New/Beta/App` and it also could be `/New/Another/Beta/App`. I don't suppose something like `*/App` or `/New/*/App` is possible instead of `/New/:placeholder/App`?

Comment: try this http://localhost/#New/Alpha/App/home

Comment: @Dalorzo This particular URL would be handled by my backend framework, only `http://localhost/New/Alpha/App` and anything after it loads AngularJS app

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you?

```
var main = angular.module("main", ["ui.bootstrap", "ngRoute"]);

main.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/New/:greek/App/home", {
        templateUrl: "assets/tpl/home.html",
        controller: "mainController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "fail"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

main.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
    console.log("home")
});
```

You could then retrieve the greek with `$routeParams.greek` from within your controller.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right direction, although I forgot to mention that the number of URL segments before `App` can change, as in it could be `/New/Alpha/App` or it could be `/New/Another/Something/App`. I don't suppose something like this is possible - `*/App/home`?

Comment: Angular does not currently support regular expressions in routes, so you will need to specify them manually.

Comment: @Romoku I see. What about 3rd party then, like https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router ?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this problem is to have the server pass the app URL to your client-side code. In other words, use server-side code to dynamically write the equivalent of the following on the page:

```
var appUrl = '/New/Alpha/App';
```

Then setting up the route provider becomes:

```
main.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when(appUrl + "/home", {
        templateUrl: "/assets/tpl/home.html",
        controller: "mainController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: appUrl + "/fail"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

That way the knowledge of the application base URL lives in one place — server-side (which makes sense as only the server is in a position to truly know, if you think about it).

---

In your specific case, if the application base URL is implicit in the URL structure, you could calculate the following client-side:

```
var appUrl = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/New\/.*\/App/);
```

Needs work, but you get the idea. Then you can set up the route provider exactly as above.